# Prime one heap Nim

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, prime-numbers, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I have been working on an interesting problem my lecturer mentioned recently. Prime Nim is a variant of the Nim game where you have a single pile with an arbitrary number $n\in \Bbb N+\{0\}$ of elements and players can take away a prime count of elements every round. Now I want to find a way to decide whether we can ensure victory in a given position (and the winning strategy, of course).

#### What I did so far:

$0$ and $1$ are clearly lost positions. On the contrary, any prime $n$ and $n+1$ are winning positions. For all other $n$ we can say that if there is no prime $p<n$ such that $n-p \notin \{n'|n'<n \land n' \text{ is lost}\}$, then $n$ is a losing position. The set of losing positions can be more formally expressed recursively based on previous such sets for smaller $n$. (In other words, this is an application of the very basic idea that a position form which we can make no move to a losing position is a losing position). All other positions are winning positions. Very simple and general.

Losing positions can be described as a sequence - http://oeis.org/A025043 (quite interestingly a subsequence of http://oeis.org/A093513). This uses the recursive nature of the problem.

An algorithm starting from the recursion edge case ($0$) and building up the sequence progressively can give us both the answer and the prospective winning strategy generated as a side-product in polynomial time.

My lecturer said the strategy-finding algorithm is probably optimal, but he also suggested there might be a simple formula to decide whether a given position can be won using an optimal strategy.

And I am stuck on it now. I guess the formula can't possibly be *that* simple, since it has to, in my opinion, include at least primality testing. I tried to determine a simple way to decide whether a number is in the sequence of losing positions, but I had no success so far. Basically, I always encounter the impenetrable problem of generating $n$th prime.

Any ideas on approaching this differently?

Comment: Every time I find a losing position $l$, $p+l$ is a winning position for all prime $p$ (play $p$).

Answer (score 5):

Are you including $1$ as a reasonable move? If so, this game ("Prime Nim" created by CE Shannon) has been [solved](http://books.google.com/books?id=8-FlYl6-ML8C&lpg=PA59&ots=vW5Sv__2or&dq=shannon%20nim%20PRIME&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q&f=false).

If not, the article above has Martin Gardner claiming an analysis of the strategy would be very difficult.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this solution. And no, 1 is not a legal move, because 1 is not a prime. It certainly isn't a simple problem...

Answer (score 4):

The lack of additional info with the OEIS sequence may indicate that the strategy is not "simple". However, here is some heuristics:

From the OEIS data, 10000 numbers up to 67673 are losers, that is more that $\frac17$, and practically  all of them are odd (I see only the exceptions $0, 10, 34, 100, 310$). *Heuristically,* this odd overweight will continue: 
Assume that there are $a$ odd and $b$ even loser numbers $x_i<N$ with $a\gg b$. Then if $N$ is even, it is a loser if none of the $a$ odd numbers $N-x_i$ is prime. This probability might be expected to be something like $$p_{\text{even}}=\left(1-\frac2{\ln N}\right)^a\approx e^{-\frac{2a}{\ln N}}.$$
On the other hand, if $N$ is odd, it is a loser only if $N-2$ is not a loser (which we will ignore) and none of the $b$ odd numbers $N-x_i$ is prime, which should be something like $$p_{\text{odd}}=\left(1-\frac2{\ln N}\right)^b\approx e^{-\frac{2b}{\ln N}}.$$
From the empirical data, it seems that $b$ is of size comparable to $\ln N$, hence $p_{\text{odd}}$ is of "reasonable" size (not really close to $0$), hence $a\approx p_{\text{odd}} N$ of size comparable to $N\gg\ln N$, which makes $p_{\text{even}}$ almost negligibly small.

I guess a similar argument might indicate that "most" loser numbers are not divisible by 3 or in fact any prime $p\ll N$ (maybe rather $p\ll \ln N$?).

But all this is far from giving a simple *definite* answer to whether a particulyr $N$ is a loser or a winner ...

Comment: Mhmm, interesting. A reasonably good probabilistic test is also a way forward. Maybe we should take prime gaps sizes of preceding primes into account, as they have some nice properties. I will definitely look into this. Thanks!