# Does Nim function for take-a-prime game is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, recursion

The Nim function for take-a-prime game $(u_n)$ is defined recursively as follows:

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u_n$ is the lowest number in $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all prime numbers $p$ (with $n−p \geq 0$), $u_n \neq u_{n-p}.$

As you can show, this sequence has interesting patterns.

[image: First terms of Nim function for take-a-prime game]

**Question: Is this sequence bounded?**

*Context:*
I came across this question ten years ago with classmates. Some of them guessed the sequence should be bounded, others thought it should have a very slow rate of divergence (such as $\log \log n$).

*Facts:*

- This is sequence [A014589](https://oeis.org/A014589) of OEIS, with first reference in 1996 in the [dissertation of Achim Flammenkamp](https://ahstat.github.io/images/2014-11-11-Nim-take-a-prime/diss.ps.gz).
- The sequence seems to take values between 0 and 11. Value 11 appears at $n=156$. I've checked all terms before $32452843$.
- Stacked plot of proportions to obtain values from 0 to 11 as the length of the sequence increases seems to converge, see following figure: 0 is on the bottom (in dark orange) and 11 is on the top (in pink).

[image: Stacked plot of proportions to obtain values from 0 to 11]

*Relation with other math.stackexchange posts:*
Some posts discuss about related sequences, and from what I can understand, it is related with the proportion of $0$ in the current A014589, see:
[Is there a last winning position in "Prime Nim"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509620/is-there-a-last-winning-position-in-prime-nim) and [Prime one heap Nim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226230/prime-one-heap-nim).

*Stronger/weaker questions:* In take-a-prime game, the subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of prime numbers. Which properties must have $S$ to bound the related Nim function for take-a-$S$ game? Are there some probabilistic results? For example: If the number of elements in $S$ smaller than $n$ is $a_n$ asymptotically, then probability [to define properly] to have a bounded Nim function is $1$.